# Name of a Batman movie with different variations of Batman

Tags: story-identification, dc, batman

About five or six years ago, I took out a Batman movie from the library, the name of which I forget, and the movie had different types of Batman's in it. For example, it had a robotic batman, an actual bat-man etc.

I have been trying for a long time to find the name of this movie but I can't for the life of me do so! If someone could be kind enough to help me out, that would be awesome!

Comment: Animated or live-action? Robotic Batman appeared in "brave and the Bold"; http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Robot_Batman_(The_Brave_and_the_Bold)

Comment: Man-Bat also appeared in Brave and the Bold; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-Bat#Television

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It may be [Batman: Gotham Knight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Gotham_Knight).

This *anime* movie was released as a tie-in between Batman Begins and The Dark Knight. The first story (titled *Have I Got a Story for You*) is about four kids that share stories about Batman, kind of "I saw him once and he looked like this". One of the kids describes him as having a robotic armor:

[image]

For another, he was sort of a vampire and could fly with his huge wings:

[image: vampire]

One other kid describes him as able to turn into a shadow. The fourth kid never saw Batman, but then Batman and the bad guy he has been fighting across those mini-stories show up where the kids are skating, and this fourth kid gets to see Batman and he looks normal.

[image: normal]

Other stories involved Batman trying a device from Lucius Fox that would deflect bullets; Batman fighting Killer Croc, The Scarecrow and Deadshot; helping two GCPD officers who get caught in the crossfire of rival gangs; and a story of Bruce Wayne learning to control pain. All episodes are anime, but Batman may have slightly different looks in each one of them.

Comment: Related, an episode of The New Batman Adventures: http://dcanimated.wikia.com/wiki/Legends_of_the_Dark_Knight

Comment: @MarkEdward, that was an amazing episode.

Comment: @MarkEdward - both were related to the story ["The Batman Nobody Knows"](http://books.google.com/books?id=TXeHAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=%22The+Batman+Nobody+Knows%22&source=bl&ots=jdUG8gWHyD&sig=T0hWVMw2ctCYP-kvH7Kfw3ynPWo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DNdNVJigPNaPNsTFguAO&ved=0CEEQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20Batman%20Nobody%20Knows%22&f=false) printed as the third feature in [Batman #250](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_250) [1973].

Answer (score 4):

In Batman: The Brave and the Bold, Season 3 there is an episode titled "[Time Out for Vengeance](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman:_The_Brave_and_the_Bold_(TV_Series)_Episode:_Time_Out_for_Vengeance!)"

It featured the following:

- Prehistoric Batman
- Pirate Batman
- Batmanicus (roman batman)
- Robot Batman

and, of course, a normal batman.